# Escape braces in ksh

Tags: linux, ksh

I am trying to prepare JSON in ksh file. I am facing this problem - I think it's because I can't properly use braces. Example:

```
RESULT="[";
COUNTRY=mCountry
LANGUAGE=mLang

AppendParams()
{
   RESULT=$RESULT"{\"site:\"$COUNTRY\",\"lang\":\"$LANGUAGE\"}";
}
AppendParams

RESULT=$RESULT"]";

echo $RESULT;
```

Output is:

```
sh-4.3$ ksh main.ksh                                                                                                                                                                                  
["site:"mCountry"] ["lang":"mLang"]
```

Instead of

```
[{"site:"mCountry","lang":"mLang"}]
```

Is there a way to disable braces or escape them? Please help.

Comment: RESULT="[{\"site\":\"${COUNTRY}\",\"lang\":\"${LANGUAGE}\"}]", perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you echo or print a variable whose value might contain a brace, double-quote the variable name like "${VARIABLE}" to avoid brace expansion. Also you might use single quotes to avoid having to escape every double-quote. Try:

```
    AppendParams()
{
   RESULT=${RESULT}'{"site:"'${COUNTRY}'","lang":'${LANGUAGE}'"}'
}
AppendParams

RESULT=$RESULT"]"

echo "$RESULT"
```

Comment: Double quotes around variable in last line helps me. Thank you!